# how to search through a vector of object pointers with a member of the class?

Tags: c++, class, vector

I am trying to figure out this program for a class. I need to simulate a playlist that can add and delete songs to and from a music library, add and delete songs to and from playlists, etc.

I have a Song class and a Playlist class, a `vector<Song*>` library (for the song library), and a `vector<Playlist>` playlists that contains a `vector<Song*>` songList. If I wanted to delete a song from library and was given the index of a song pointer in the library vector, how would I check if that "song" is in any of the "playlists"?
here is the related sections of code that I have:

```
    using namespace std;

    class Song {
    public:
         Song(string title, string line, int count) {
              name = title;
              firstLine = line;
              playCount = count;
         }
         string GetName() {
              return name;
         }

         string GetFirstLine() {
              return firstLine;
         }
    private:
         string name;
         string firstLine;
         int playCount;;
    };

    class Playlist {
    public:
         Playlist(string name = "none"){
              pName = name;
         }
         void AddSong(Song* song) {
              songPtr.push_back(song);
         }
         void RemoveSong(int songIndex) {
              songPtr.erase(songPtr.begin() + songIndex);
         }
         string GetSongAtIndex(int index) {
              return (songPtr.at(index))->GetName();
         }

    private:
         string pName;
         vector<Song*> songPtr;
    };

    int main() {
    string userIn;
    vector<Song*> library;
    vector<Playlist> playlists;

    // code for adding songs to library using "new"
    // code for adding songs to playlist using "new"
    

    // delete song from library
    // first, list songs in library
        size = library.size();
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cout << "  " << i << ": " << (library.at(i))->GetName();
            cout << endl;
        }
        // have user pick which song they want erased
        cout << "Pick a song index number: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin >> sIndex;

        // FIXME: check if song is in any playlist, and if it is, remove it
        string songName = (library.at(sIndex))->GetName();
        int size = playlists.size(); //remove song from playlists
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int size2 = (playlists.at(i)).GetPSize();
            for (j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
                string tempName = (playlists.at(j)).GetSongAtIndex(j);
                if (tempName == songName) {
                    (playlists.at(i)).RemoveSong(j);
                }
            }
        }
        // code to delete song from library and free the memory
```

What I have doesn't work, when I try to list the songs in the library after I delete it, it gives me an "out of range" error and crashes the program. when I comment out the parts about finding it in a playlist, it deletes from library just fine. It's only when I try to check if that song is in the playlist that I get the error. I am relatively new to programming so it likely that I am just missing something, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Instead of `vector<Song*> songPtr;` you need to use `vector<Song> songPtr;` or `vector<unique_ptr<Song>> songPtr;`. Storing the pointers in vector is not a good idea, you'll get memory leaks. For example, `songPtr.erase(songPtr.begin() + songIndex);` leaks RAM.

Comment: For th e actual question, you can use [`std::find_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Comment: And your indentation is not good. If you don't fix it there are very few people who will read your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove an element from a playlist you should not increment the index and should decrease the size:

```
// check if song is in any playlist, and if it is, remove it
string songName = library.at(sIndex)->GetName();
int size = playlists.size(); //remove song from playlists
for (j = 0; j < size2; ) {                // do not increment j here
    string tempName = playlists.at(i).GetSongAtIndex(j); // i, not j for playlists.at()
    if (tempName == songName) {
        playlists.at(i).RemoveSong(j);  // j remains the same
        --size2;                          // one element less
    } else {
        ++j;                              // increment here
    }
}
```